# Post a form on click of table row

Tags: ajax, laravel, routes

I wanted post a form on click of row of table and pass that row data with it. I am passing data to controller using ajax.

```
$("#return_table tr").click(function(e){
  $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
    var name = $("#cityName").val();
    var initial = $("#cityInitial").val();
   $.ajax({
     headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') 
     },
    type:'post',
    data: $('#return_flight').serialize(),
    success: function () {
     alert('form was submitted');
    }
  }); 
});
```

This is my ajax.

My route is `Route::post('/dashboard/return','Users\BookTicketController@retrunTime');`

When I click on any row then I am getting error that POST http://127.0.0.1/dashboard/return 500 (Internal Server Error)

What is a issue with this code?

Comment: add url to ajax.

Comment: Yea its added. url: 'http://127.0.0.1:80/dashboard/return'

Comment: url should be only what you added in routes not the whole path.

Comment: Check this question it might help you: [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51373133/ajax-crud-error-while-performing-store-method/51373949#51373949)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not in this code It probably occurring at your backend code, check your `retrunTime` function implementation.

check out this link understand more about why and when 500 error occurs.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/500